# I have to reload shell (exec $SHELL -l) to load all PATHs on Fish shell

Tags: macos, shell, fish

I set Fish as a login shell referenced here(https://fishshell.com/docs/current/index.html#default-shell).

Then installed `rbenv`.

But I have to reload Fish shell to call `rbenv`.

Easy to understand to look at below.

```php
yas  ~  ps -f
  UID   PID  PPID   C STIME   TTY           TIME CMD
  501 55722 55721   0  5:09PM ttys001    0:00.02 -fish //set fish as login shell

yas  ~  rbenv // couldn't find rbenv
fish: Unknown command: rbenv

yas  ~  echo $PATH // couldn't find a path to rbenv                                                                                                                                       
/Users/yas/.anyenv/envs/pyenv/shims /opt/homebrew/bin /opt/homebrew/sbin /opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/bin /opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@3/bin /usr/local/bin /usr/bin /bin /usr/sbin /sbin /Users/yas/.anyenv/envs/pyenv/bin

yas  ~  exec $SHELL -l // Reloading the shell 

yas  ~  rbenv --version // succeeded
rbenv 1.2.0-14-gc6cc0a1

yas  ~  echo $PATH // Paths are added after reloading the shell.
/Users/yas/.anyenv/envs/rbenv/shims /Users/yas/.anyenv/envs/pyenv/shims /opt/homebrew/bin /opt/homebrew/sbin /opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/bin /opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@3/bin /usr/local/bin /usr/bin /bin /usr/sbin /sbin /opt/homebrew/bin /opt/homebrew/sbin /Users/yas/.anyenv/envs/pyenv/bin /Users/yas/.anyenv/envs/pyenv/bin /Users/yas/.anyenv/envs/rbenv/bin

yas  ~  ps -f // shell path has changed from  -fish after reloading.
  UID   PID  PPID   C STIME   TTY           TIME CMD
  501 55722 55721   0  5:09PM ttys001    0:00.16 /opt/homebrew/bin/fish -l
```

Inside `~/.config/fish/config.fish`

```php
if status is-interactive
    # Commands to run in interactive sessions can go here
end
eval (/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)
status --is-interactive; and source (anyenv init -|psub)
set fish_function_path $fish_function_path "/Users/yas/.anyenv/envs/pyenv/versions/3.10.5/lib/python3.10/site-packages/powerline/bindings/fish"
powerline-setup
```

I don't like to type `exec $SHELL -l` on every launch.
Does anyone help me out with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is https://github.com/anyenv/anyenv/pull/99 - anyenv's pyenv setup interferes with other envs:

> In the current situation, pyenv init --path also causes a problem with anyenv. When logging into zsh, the initialization process stops at pyenv and further (such as rbenv, or sbtenv) are impossible.

As a workaround, it should be possible to just run `anyenv init -` twice, since it seems that the pyenv setup is skipped or succeeds the second time around (this would be what fixes it when you run fish twice!):

```
status --is-interactive; and source (anyenv init -|psub)
status --is-interactive; and source (anyenv init -|psub)
```

Which can be simplified to

```
if status is-interactive
    anyenv init - | source
    anyenv init - | source
end
```

Comment: I use your command thankfully till the issue is fixed.